# Symfony Enum Type with formType

Tags: php, forms, symfony, enums, entity

I have a symfony entity that have an enum type field  and I want to generate a form type for it.
I want to know the right way to do that.

this is my entity :

```
<?php

namespace EvalBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * SessionEvaluation
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="session_evaluation")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="EvalBundle\Repository\SessionEvaluationRepository")
 */
class SessionEvaluation
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="startDate", type="datetime")
     */
    private $startDate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="endDate", type="datetime")
     */
    private $endDate;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", columnDefinition="enum('annual', 'intermediate')")
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * One SessionEvaluation has Many PerformanceEvaluation.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PerformanceEvaluation", mappedBy="sessionEvaluation")
     */
    private $performanceEvaluations;

    /**
     * One SessionEvaluation has Many Evaluation.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Evaluation", mappedBy="sessionEvaluation")
     */
    private $evaluations;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return SessionEvaluation
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set startDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $startDate
     *
     * @return SessionEvaluation
     */
    public function setStartDate($startDate)
    {
        $this->startDate = $startDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get startDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getStartDate()
    {
        return $this->startDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set endDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $endDate
     *
     * @return SessionEvaluation
     */
    public function setEndDate($endDate)
    {
        $this->endDate = $endDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get endDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getEndDate()
    {
        return $this->endDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param string $type
     *
     * @return SessionEvaluation
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

and here is the formType :

```
<?php

namespace EvalBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class SessionEvaluationType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('Name', TextType::class, array(
            'attr'=> array('class'=>'form-control')
        ))
                ->add('startDate', DateType::class, array(
                    'format' => 'yyyy MM dd'
                ))
                ->add('endDate')
                ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        'Annuel' => true,
                        'Itérmidaire' => false,
                    ),
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'dropdown')

                ))
            ->add('Lancer', SubmitType::class, array(
                'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')));

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'EvalBundle\Entity\SessionEvaluation'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'evalbundle_sessionevaluation';
    }


}
```

> the field with enum type is : type

I've defined it as choiceType in the form, is this a good way to do it for save the entity instance in the database after submit the form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enum type can be set like you did with annotation in your entity. However you have to secure what string is pass in the function setType for be sure it's part of your enum.

You should do this

```
public function setType($type)
{
    if (!in_array($type, array('annual', 'intermediate'))) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid type");
    }
    $this->type = $type;
}
```

Then in your form, you will be sure that the value to save in database passed by your ChoiceType is like your enum. By the way you can choose any type who return string but ChoiceType is the best in this case because your user can select string you have chosen. But for be sure he doesn't pass other value it's a good practice to secure the setter on server side like above.

Otherwise you can still use an another solution who consist in create a specific type for your Enum who can be found [here](http://www.maxpou.fr/dealing-with-enum-symfony-doctrine/) or  [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/mysql-enums.html) but the first solution is fine.